# How to handle distributed excessive scraping

Tags: web-scraping, iis

For context - I have data which I make available to download entirely via XML on one subdomain and human-friendly access to the data via queries to suit whatever the human user is looking for on another subdomain. The flat files are written every 30 minutes, the rest is served from a datamart that is updated relatively quickly. Ideally, scrapers would use the XML side and humans would use the human-friendly side.

But certain scrapers have decided that they're special and need to scrape the human-friendly side, even if the way they do so is indistinguishable from a DDoS attack. I've dealt with the ones that (ab)use cloud hosting services like AWS and done my best to contact the ones I can and push them to use XML in as polite of terms as I can. I've also gone over the 2010 "how do I prevent scraping" question here and I'm already doing what I'm able to of the recommendations there.

Sadly, that leaves a distributed network of ISP-registered addresses (mostly Charter/Spectrum owned) that is my problem. These are what I'm asking how to deal with. They will scrape 3 specific pages that are normally accessed only by iframes on a page that they never load. Their referrer is blank, their user agent fakes multiple common browsers in rapid succession, and they only hit about 100-300 times per IP address. That much is consistent enough that I'm confident that all the thousands of them are the same code being run. It's clearly targeted at getting a specific subset of our data (just the 3 pages with about 1500 different parameters sent to them in total) that we do export to XML, but if this were intentionally malicious, I would say it looked like a botnet, but I can't imagine someone using a botnet to carelessly grab freely shared data.

I'm not allowed to force a captcha on it for all users, and since this is using thousands of addresses across dozens of common ISPs, I can only apply it after the fact.

I thought about leveraging the lack of referrer, but that's an easy code patch for them and it's going to have a lot of false positives.

To summarize the problem - I am facing a scraper network hopping between thousands of ISP-registered IP addresses at a high enough rate that cumulatively our datamart MsSQL server can't handle all the requested queries the pages require alongside normal traffic.

Is there anything that I can do other than captcha that might stop or at least reduce the excessive rate of these?

This is using IIS, ASPX and MsSQL.